# Is $X-X$ a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If $X$ is a random variable, is then $X-X$ also a random variable, since the value of $X-X$ is definite and independent of the outcome of a random event?

Comment: Yes. $\qquad\qquad$

Comment: Yes.  $(X-X)(\omega)=0$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, so is measurable.

Comment: Are you asking why the constant (/zero) function is measurable or what?

Comment: Yes, a constant is a random variable with a degenerate distribution. It takes the given value with probability $1$.

Comment: Random variable is just a confusing name for a measurable function and indeed a constant function is measurable.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are variables, yes; $X-X$ has a [degenerate distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution).